# RUNSTATS after run a LOAD utility in db2

Tags: db2, load

I have a bash that loads 100 csv files into one db2 table using the LOAD utility, my question is: should I executes a RUNSTATS after each file is loaded or just when all the files are loaded? Currently the bash is running a RUNSTATS after each file is loaded but sometimes the RUNSTATS fails with below error:

DB2 runstats throws exception " The utility could not generate statistics. Error "-911" was returned.. SQLCODE=-2310, SQLSTATE= , DRIVER=3.53.71"

Comment: Is the target table distributed? Is the target table partitioned? (Or both of the above?).  Is the target table compressed, or organize by column?  Usually best to do the runstats at the end of all loading. But if you get a -911 then you should check which other jobs are using the table concurrently, and either do the loading at a quiet time, or arrange for a smarter runstats profile, perhaps with sampling, or different kinds of collections of statistics, different columns getting distribution stats etc, and especially with after -911.   This is administration, not programming.

Comment: You need RUNSTATS on a table to better optimize DML statements using this table. If you run them between your LOAD commands AND a previous LOAD changed the data significantly (let's say, more than 10% of rows was added), then you should run RUNSTATS. Otherwise - no.